# Kafka Streams slows/doesn't read data post few days

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafkaStreams application which reads data from 4 topics Lets say A,B,C,D with partitions 5 each. Topic B is used for creating the global Ktable which is used for joining data from topic A.

2 topics(A,B) are ingested with 2-3 Million records on each topic in short span 20-30 Mins for every 3 hours. the other two topics(C,D) receives 50 messages in a hour (mostly metadata) .
Under normal conditions the application takes max of 30 mins for processing the entire records that are received on topics A, B.

All of a sudden application slows down it takes more than 6 hours for processing the same number of records, but if i restart the application it completed the processing under 20-30 mins. There is no exception, error why/what is the reason for such sudden slow down of processing.

Kafka & VM on which Application running are with in same network and there is no network issue.

Any pointer(s), direction(s) for finding what could be the cause would be great.

Thanks !

Comment: I would try to check out JMX metrics to see what changes... Could you have a memory leak and the app starts to trash after some time?

Comment: Any specific jmx metric(s) to watch for.